# Использование переменной из другого неймпрейса в Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Здраствуйте!

Столкнулся с проблемой переменных в выборке данных с помощью laravel eloquent.

```
        $storage_item = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('id', $request->storage_search)->first();
        if ($storage_item->type !== StoragesLocationsProducts::BOX_TYPE) {
            $buildQuery->whereNotNull('products.storage_location_product_id')->where(function ($query) {
                global $storage_item;
                if ($storage_item->type === StoragesLocationsProducts::STORAGE_TYPE) {
                    $storages = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('storage_id', $storage_item->storage_id)->get();
                    foreach ($storages as $id => $storage) {
                        $query->orWhere('products.storage_location_product_id', '=', $storage->id);
                    }
                    
                } else if ($storage_item->type === StoragesLocationsProducts::LOCATION_TYPE) {
                    $locations = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('location_id', $storage_item->location_id)->get();
                    foreach ($locations as $id => $location) {
                        $query->orWhere('products.storage_location_product_id', '=', $location->id);
                    }
         
                }
            });    
        }
```

Когда делаю подобный поиск то получаю ошибку `Trying to get property 'type' of non-object`.

Как я могу использовать мою переменную `$storage_item` внутри функции поиска в eloquent?

Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: dd($storage_item) в моменте, где ошибка покажите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем `global` ? через `use` указываем переменную из внешнего контекста

```
$storage_item = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('id', $request->storage_search)->first();

if ($storage_item->type !== StoragesLocationsProducts::BOX_TYPE) {
    $buildQuery->whereNotNull('products.storage_location_product_id')->where(function ($query) use ($storage_item) {
                     
        if ($storage_item->type === StoragesLocationsProducts::STORAGE_TYPE) {
            $storages = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('storage_id', $storage_item->storage_id)->get();
            foreach ($storages as $id => $storage) {
                $query->orWhere('products.storage_location_product_id', '=', $storage->id);
            }

        } else if ($storage_item->type === StoragesLocationsProducts::LOCATION_TYPE) {
            $locations = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('location_id', $storage_item->location_id)->get();
            foreach ($locations as $id => $location) {
                $query->orWhere('products.storage_location_product_id', '=', $location->id);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Также совет по оптимизации, чтобы не гонять столько циклов:
Этот код

```
if ($storage_item->type === StoragesLocationsProducts::STORAGE_TYPE) {
    $storages = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('storage_id', $storage_item->storage_id)->get();
    foreach ($storages as $id => $storage) {
        $query->orWhere('products.storage_location_product_id', '=', $storage->id);
    }

} else if ($storage_item->type === StoragesLocationsProducts::LOCATION_TYPE) {
    $locations = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('location_id', $storage_item->location_id)->get();
    foreach ($locations as $id => $location) {
        $query->orWhere('products.storage_location_product_id', '=', $location->id);
    }

}
```

Лучше заменить на

```
switch ($storage_item->type) {
    case StoragesLocationsProducts::STORAGE_TYPE:
        $storages_id = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('storage_id', $storage_item->storage_id)
            ->select('id')->pluck('id')->toArray();
        if(count($storages_id)) {
            $query->whereIn('products.storage_location_product_id', $storages_id);
        }
        break;
    case StoragesLocationsProducts::LOCATION_TYPE:
        $locations_id = StoragesLocationsProducts::where('location_id', $storage_item->location_id)
            ->select('id')->pluck('id')->toArray();
        if(count($locations_id)) {
            $query->whereIn('products.storage_location_product_id', $locations);
        }
        break;
}
```

Либо еще проще, если для всех `type` логика построения запроса одинаковая:

```
$type_listing = [
    StoragesLocationsProducts::STORAGE_TYPE => 'storage_id',
    StoragesLocationsProducts::LOCATION_TYPE => 'location_id'
];

$id_listing = StoragesLocationsProducts::where($type_listing[$storage_item->type], $storage_item->storage_id)
    ->select('id')->pluck('id')->toArray();
if(count($id_listing)) {
    $query->whereIn('products.storage_location_product_id', $id_listing);
}
```